# Error "Incorrect syntax near the keyword where"

Tags: c#, database, syntax-error

```
private void btnguardar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            con.Open();
            string Query = "INSERT Produtos where (id_subcategoria= @id_subcategoria, nome_produto= @nome_produto, quantidade= @quantidade, preco_unitario= @preco_unitario, iva= @iva)";
            SqlCommand createCommand = new SqlCommand(Query, con);
            createCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id_subcategoria", this.label4.Text);
            createCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nome_produto", this.txt_nproduto.Text);
            createCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@quantidade", this.txtquantidade.Text);
            createCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@preco_unitario", Convert.ToDecimal(this.txtpreco.Text));
            createCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@iva", Convert.ToDecimal(this.txtiva.Text));
            createCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            MessageBox.Show("Registo adicionado com sucesso!", this.Text, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            con.Close();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }

        //"insert into Produtos (id_subcategoria, nome_produto, quantidade, preco_unitario, iva) values('" + this.label4.Text + "','" + this.txt_nproduto.Text + "','" + this.txtquantidade.Text + "','" + this.txtpreco.Text + "','" + this.txtiva.Text + "') ;"; 
    }
```

I'm getting an error while clicking at btnguardar, and open MessageBox saying "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'where'"

Can you guys help me with this matter?

Comment: What version of SQL is this?  Microsoft SQL?  There's no where clause for the [Insert statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174335.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

Comment: Your commented out line is closer to the correct syntax (although you should use parameters).

Comment: you error are on your query statement its with out insert into table, you are setting with out into statement

Comment: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
string Query = 
"INSERT INTO Produtos (id_subcategoria, nome_produto, quantidade, preco_unitario, iva) 
VALUES (@id_subcategoria, @nome_produto, @quantidade, @preco_unitario, @iva)";
```